# UnknownError in Safari 7.1 when creating multiple object stores with IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, safari, indexeddb

I wanted to sanity check and see if anyone else was having a problem with Safari 7.1 and IndexedDB. Seems that I get an error of type UnknownError, which, according to the spec at  http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/ occurs when "The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other errors." This occurs the second time I call this function, after the first call has called the callbacks (either onSuccess or onError). Here is my function for creating an object store, which works in both Chrome and Firefox.

```
IndexedDBClient.prototype.createObjectStore = function(options) {
  if (this.checkIfObjectStoreExists(options.objectStoreName)) {
    options.onError(this.objectStoreDNEMessage);
    return;
  }

  var objectStore;

  var objectStoreCreated = false;
  var databaseOpened = false;

  var version = this.database.version;
  var dbName = this.database.name;
  this.database.close();
  var request = indexedDB.open(dbName, ++version);
  var that = this;

  request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
    that.database = e.target.result;
    objectStore = that.database.createObjectStore(options.objectStoreName, { keyPath: options.keyPathName });

    objectStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(e) {
      objectStoreCreated = true;
      successCallback();
    }

    objectStore.transaction.onerror = function(e) {
      options.onError(e);
    };
  };

  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    databaseOpened = true;
    successCallback();
  }

  request.onerror = function(e) {
    options.onError(e);
  };

  request.onblocked = function(e) {
    typeof options.onBlocked === 'function' && options.onBlocked();
  };

  function successCallback() {
    // This is needed because we must be sure that both the objectstore creation transaction has completed,
    // and the db open request has fired the onsuccess event.
    objectStoreCreated && databaseOpened && options.onSuccess(objectStore);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexedDB API in Safari browser has [bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136937) on multiple stores transaction.